# Within Panels, get node ids that contain taxonomy term

Tags: panels

I have a panel with a content pane that shows a node based on the Taxonomy Term Name in the URL of the panel.
This is working using  "(Content) Content: Has taxonomy term ID" as a contextual filter, and "From panel argument" within the content pane.

I am also wanting to add the add comments form to the panel. Which could be done using the nid of the node displayed in the above mentioned panel.

So, from within panels, how can I get the nid of a node that has the taxonomy term as a field, where the taxonomy term is within the URL?

Can taxonomy_select_nodes($array_with_tids); be used within panels?

Using Drupal 7, Panels 7.x-3.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than getting the nid from within Panels, I just used taxonomy_select_nodes and passed the result to panels as a second argument in the URL eg panels-view/%tid/%nid.

This solved my problem.

Thanks